# Android Compose Map Clustering not working for two map markers

Tags: google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using the [Clustering](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-compose#clustering) compose component to show some map marker and everything is looking good, some of the markers are been clustered. But, when I have just two map markers, very close to each other, they are no been grouped. It seems like the clustering component just group 3 or more map markers. Is it possible to set on this component to group 2 or more map markers?

Ok, I'm still trying to find another way to increase the min cluster items, but so far I as able to do like this:

```
SideEffect {
        if (clusterManager?.renderer != renderer) {
            (renderer as? DefaultClusterRenderer)?.minClusterSize = 2
            clusterManager?.renderer = renderer ?: return@SideEffect
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that the community can use and test and understand why things are not working on your end.